# 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Everything was working fine until I tried "8.1 Rendering Partial Collections" I started getting this error message:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> If you are the administrator of this
>   website, then please read this web
>   application's log file and/or the web
>   server's log file to find out what
>   went wrong.

In the development log file I have:

```
Started GET "/posts/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 16:53:35 +0300
  Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  [1m[36mPost Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
ERROR: compiling _app_views_posts_show_html_erb___599541849308356030_2168837280__3307996878912411319 RAISED /Users/username/Projects/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb:20: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
...         :collection => @post.comments );@output_buf...
...                                ^
Function body:           def _app_views_posts_show_html_erb___599541849308356030_2168837280__3307996878912411319(local_assigns)
            _old_virtual_path, @_virtual_path = @_virtual_path, "posts/show";_old_output_buffer = @output_buffer;;@output_buffer = ActionView::OutputBuffer.new;@output_buffer.safe_concat('<p class="notice">');@output_buffer.append= ( notice );@output_buffer.safe_concat('</p>
 
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  ');@output_buffer.append= ( @post.name );@output_buffer.safe_concat('
');@output_buffer.safe_concat('</p>
```

What's wrong?

Please help.

EDIT: views/posts/show.html.erb:

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>
 
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment",
           :collection => @post.comments %>
 
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
 
<br />
 
<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %> |
```

EDIT 2:

Here’s views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<p>
  <b>Commenter:</b>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>
 
<p>
  <b>Comment:</b>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
```

If I remove the following the app runs:

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment",
           :collection => @post.comments %>
```

However, if I change the content of _comment.html.erb to blablabla it still show the same error.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your view. Can you show us the view code?

Comment: Hello, I added it to the post.

Comment: can you show your partial too please?

Comment: What version of Ruby and Rails are you running?

Comment: MacBook$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
MacBook$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.7

Comment: What happens if instead of `<%= render :partial => "comments/comment", :collection => @post.comments %>` you try `<%= render @post.comments %>`? What happens when you remove the collection to be rendered to the partial, is it able to render it then? And finally what about moving the collection to be rendered onto the same line as the render :partial statement.

Comment: "And finally what about moving the collection to be rendered onto the same line as the render :partial statement." that fixed the problem. Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'"*

You appear to be missing a closing parenthesis somewhere. Without seeing the surrounding code that's the best we can do.

Edit: by "surrounding code" I mean surrounding `views/posts/show.html.erb:20`.

Comment: I added the whole view in the original post.

Comment: @emurad: Have you also put the partial view `_comments.html.erb` in the correct place? If so what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

I guess u have missed ')' in `views/posts/show.html.erb line no 20`. can you please check that one.

Answer (score 0):

You get that message when you have an **error within an error** in Rails. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043842/886745) has greater context about why this happens and how you may troubleshoot this.