# Rails full error page not showing for view errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, view, stack-trace

I have a view named `new.html.erb` with the following code:

```
<%= some_non_existent_thing.imaginary_method %>
```

Now, I only see one simple 500 error page, like that:

> **500 Internal Server Error**
>   If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

Shouldn't I see a pretty formatted page with some information about the exception?

I'm not sure I miss something here, but I believe rails used to show the full error page in development environment when there is something wrong in the view.

Comment: so, this happened in your dev box or places like Heroku?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that you are running the development environment? Check that `RAILS_ENV=development` or that you are running `rails server -e development`.

Then check your development.rb file, you should have the following line in it

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have an **exception inside an exception**, Rails has a [middleware that catches it and returns a FAILSAFE_RESPONSE with the following copy](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c3e02cb520a1a7a913dd76d631bea03d6dd9764/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L17-L24):

> 500 Internal Server Error
> If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

A nice way to troubleshoot this is to compare your custom error code with the sample code provided in the [Rails 4.2.0 guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.0/action_controller_overview.html#custom-errors-page).

I'm pointing to that particular version because that whole section was removed in the [Rails 5.0.0 guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/action_controller_overview.html).

Ideally, you should keep your error views, layout, and controller as free of logic as possible, to avoid running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Anton mentions in the answer below, confirm that your `config/environments/development.rb` has:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

and that you are running the server in development mode.

I had ensured the above and still observed the error.
This happened in my case, because my logger had some errors. I was using a custom log formatter, which used the `String#%` method to format the log. `%` seems to be very buggy and leads to all these weird errors. I figured this one out by adding a `debugger` line to the controller method and stepping through into the implicit render function call. It hit the bug and reported it as a `malformed format string` error.

This was the log formatter I was using before, which caused the bugs [I had added it to an initializer file]:

```
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "%-7s #{msg}\n" % severity
  end
end
```

These modifications fixed the bug:

```
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    severity_prefix = "[#{severity}]".ljust(7)
    "#{severity_prefix} #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the code is not compilable, for example if you have an if statement missing an end.

Comment: In development, it should show the exception and not the 500 error page.