# Axios - NodeJS Always returns 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have one node-express project for api gateway.

This is my gateway code;

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8081',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cacheControl({
    noCache: true
}));
dotenv.load();
// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return {
        success: true,
        status: response.status,
        data: response
    };
}, error => {
    let e = error;
    let errObject = {
        response: {
            data: e.response.data
        }
    };
    return Promise.reject(errObject);
});
app.post('/service', (req, res) => {
       if (req.body.type.indexOf('auth' > -1)) {
          let payload = {
              url: process.env.DEV_ENDPOINT + req.body.type,
              method: req.body.method,
              data: req.body.data
          };
           try {
              return axios(payload).then(function(response){
                   res.send(response);
               }).catch((error) => {
                   res.send(error);
               })
           } catch (e) {
               console.log("error");
               console.log(e);
           }
       } else {
           // verify it first
       }
});

app.listen(PORT, error => (
  error
    ? console.error(error)
    : console.info(`Listening on port ${PORT}. Visit http://localhost:${PORT}/ in your browser.`)
));

module.exports = app;
```

Now, the problem is here; in interceptors axios always catches error.
Error;

> 500 Internal Server Error. If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.

In postman, I am sending request to actual api and its working. But in axios, somehow, it doesn't working. It always sends error text.

Comment: What message does the server console show?

Comment: The error is not in try catch block, its in axios catch block. Obviously, interceptor catching this error and sends it. Only thing i can see is "500 Internal Server Error" that's all. Nothing more. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could see information about the error in console.

```
 app.post ('/ service', (req, res) => {
 if (req.body.type.indexOf ('auth'> -1))

 // Here in the .then, somehow introduce it
 // in your code, try it.
 .then (res => {
        console.log (res);
```

There are possible reasons and possible solutions to that internal server error, take a look at the following [link](https://kaloraat.com/articles/laravel-500-internal-server-error-on-post-request), although it is from Laravel, you can have an idea, since what is stated in the reasons is very good to keep in mind as a concept of the error.

The same thing happened to me, in my case, I had an error in the data type in the Schema, in addition a fix that did not correspond in this.axios.post was happening. Also, I was not showing the answer in the console as I put it in the code. Hehe, I'm new to APIREST

In case it helps you, my code is:

```
  this.axios.post ('/ inventory', 
  this.ArticlesForm)
  .then (res => {
        console.log (res);
      this.invent.unshift (res.data)
      })
    .catch (function (error) {//
    console.log (error.toJSON); //
    console.log ('in inventory.vue')
});
},
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
router.post ('/ inventory', async (req, res) => {
const body = req.body;
try {
const DB note = await Invent.create (body);
res.status (200) .json (notaDB);
} catch (error) {
 // return res.status (500) .json ({
 // message: 'An error occurred in post',
//error
//})

 }
```

As it is, insert correctly with the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are consuming a Rails application server, you may be getting this error due to an exception happening inside an exception. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69043842/886745) has more details about it.